# Qt outputs a tiny box?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

For my class, I'm supposed to code the framework of an iTunes-esque program called Qtunes. I decided to do this by using 3 ListWidgets and a TableWidget. So I wrote the following code in Qt creator(we're supposed to code it by hand not using the designer),

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include<QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)

//    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
//{
//    ui->setupUi(this);
//}
{
    genreList = new QListWidget(this);
    artistList = new QListWidget(this);
    albumList = new QListWidget(this);

    songTable = new QTableWidget(this);

    genLabel = new QLabel(this);
    genLabel->setText("Genre");

    artistLabel = new QLabel(this);
    artistLabel->setText("Artist");

    albLabel = new QLabel(this);
    albLabel->setText("Album");


    QHBoxLayout *labelLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    labelLayout->addWidget(genLabel);
    labelLayout->addWidget(artistLabel);
    labelLayout->addWidget(albLabel);

    QHBoxLayout *topLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLayout->addWidget(genreList);
    topLayout->addWidget(artistList);
    topLayout->addWidget(albumList);

    QHBoxLayout *bottomLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    bottomLayout->addWidget(songTable);

    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(labelLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(topLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(bottomLayout);

    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle("Version 2");
}
```

I didn't expect to have it working but expected to at least see the listWidgets and such. Instead I got this:

http://postimage.org/image/krrs2ijmx/

I know I'm doing something wrong somewhere and I've spent the last couple of hours trying to find where.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: try creating labels,ListWidget and TableWidget without a parent, I mean like this genLabel = new QLabel(),genreList = new QListWidget(); and then add these widgets to the layout

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    //...
    //Skip your code 
    //...
    centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
    setWindowTitle("Version 2");
}
```

Comment: Dude. Thank you so much. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I did wrong. Seriously man, thank you so much.